# how to convert string to DateTime as UTC as simple as that

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

assume I have this string : 
How can I convert it to DateTimeOffset object that will have UTC time - means -00:00 as Time Zone - even if I run it on machine on a specific timezone?

Assume String:
"2012-10-08T04:50:12.0000000"

Convert.ToDateTime("2012-10-08T04:50:12.0000000" + "Z");

--> DateTime d = {10/8/2012 6:50:12 AM}
and I want it to be
**DateTime d = {10/8/2012 4:50:12 AM}**
as if it will understand I want the date as simple as it comes (BTW - my machine is in timezone +02:00)

Comment: so do you want DateTime or DateTimeOffset?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use `DateTimeOffset.Parse(string).UtcDateTime`.

Comment: Do not know if something has changed in .NET since this was asked but I had to append ToString() to the end to get this to work, but it works perfectly    DateTimeOffset.Parse(string).UtcDateTime.ToString()

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Using `DateTimeOffset.Parse(string)` or `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(string)` with the `.UtcDateTime` converter correctly changed the kind of the `DateTime` to UTC, but also converted the time.

To get to a `DateTime` that has the same time as the original string time, but in UTC use the following:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(string, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var universalDateTime = DateTime.Parse(your_date_time_string).ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: how do you reverse the universalDataTime back into a string?  926291224800000  given this value

Answer (score 1):

I did this by checking the `DateTimeKind`. On my function, 2 different types of date-times are coming. What I want is to convert UTC time to local time from the below function. Input parameter `date` is always coming as UTC.

Eg inputs: `2021-01-19 07:43:00 AM` and `01/07/2021 02:16:00 PM +00:00`

```
public static DateTime GetDateTime(string date)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(date, GetCulture()); //invarient culture

            if (parsedDate.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
            {
                parsedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(parsedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }
            
            return parsedDate.ToLocalTime();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using, `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` in `DateTime.Parse(...)` will do the job,

**Ex:**

`DateTime.Parse("2023-01-02 9:26", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)`

then the parsed datetime will be in UTC

Comment: This takes the string "2023-08-31T23:59:59Z"  parses it as local and then applies the offset to convert to UTC.