# ASP.NET MVC convert DateTime to UTC to send to API

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to send a start date and end date to an API in UTC format, I have tried the following:

```
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(start + "T00:00:00Z").ToUniversalTime();
DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(end + "T23:59:59Z").ToUniversalTime();
```

But it appears they are not converting to UTC, what would be the proper way to take startDate and endDate and convert them over to UTC?

start is a string and is 2018-08-31 and end date is also a string and is 2018-08-31 I added the times in the code above to cover the full date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert string to DateTime as UTC as simple as that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254211/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-as-utc-as-simple-as-that)

Comment: Z means "Zulu" also known as UTC. You are trying to convert a UTC time to UTC - I imagine it is working just fine :)

Comment: What are your incorrect results? What is your local timezone offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install below package from NuGet package manager and referenced it in your project:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Now you can easily use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object value)` method for serialize any objects to Json.

For converting DateTime to UTC use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime dateTime)` method.

In your case:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-31");
DateTime dateTimeToUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date);
string dateInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dateTimeToUtc);
```

the variable dateInJson will have value like `2018-08-30T19:30:00Z`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want `endDate` to represent the last possible moment on the given date in UTC:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(end, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
                        .AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
```

A few other things:

- `ToUniversalTime` converts to UTC *from the computer's local time zone* (unless `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc`).  You should generally avoid it unless the computer's local time zone is relevant to your situation.
- In the above code, you need both `AssumeUniversal` to indicate that the input date is meant to be interpreted as UTC, and `AdjustToUniversal` to indicate that you want the output value to be kept in terms of UTC and not the computer's local time zone.
- UTC is not a "format".  Your combined date and time strings would be in ISO 8601 extended format (also RFC 3339 compliant).
- Generally, try not to use `Convert.ToDateTime`.  It is equivalent to `DateTime.Parse` with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and no `DateTimeStyles`.  That may work for some scenarios, but it is usually better to be more specific.
- `.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)` is there to get you to the last representable tick on that date.  That allows for inclusive comparison between start and end, however it comes with the disadvantage of not being able to subtract the two values and get a whole 24 hours.  Thus, it is usually better to simply track `00:00` of one day to `00:00` of the next day, then use *exclusive* comparison on the end date.  (Only the start date should be compared inclusively.)

  In other words, instead of:

  ```
  2018-08-31T00:00:00.0000000Z <= someValueToTest <= 2018-08-31T23:59:59.9999999Z
  ```

  Do this:

  ```
  2018-08-31T00:00:00.0000000Z <= someValueToTest < 2018-09-01T00:00:00.0000000Z
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Z

```
        string start = "2018-08-31";
        string end = "2018-08-31";

        DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(start + "T00:00:00");
        DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(end + "T23:59:59");

        Console.WriteLine(startDate);                   // 8/31/2018 12:00:00 (Local)
        Console.WriteLine(startDate.ToUniversalTime()); // 8/31/2018 5:00:00 (UTC)
        Console.WriteLine(endDate);                     // 8/31/2018 11:59:59 (Local)
        Console.WriteLine(endDate.ToUniversalTime());   // 9/1/2018 4:59:59 (UTC)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are sending dynamic linq like me, you'd need datetime in a text form.
If you are dealing with UTC then:

```
//specify utc just to avoid any problem
DateTime dateTime = yourDateTime.SetKindUtc();

var filterToSendToApi = $"CreatedTime>={dateTime.ToStringUtc()}"
```

helpers:

```
      public static string ToStringUtc(this DateTime time)
        {
            return $"DateTime({time.Ticks}, DateTimeKind.Utc)";
        }

      public static DateTime SetKindUtc(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
            {
                return dateTime;
            }

            return DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }
```