# How to convert this UTC datetime string to DateTime object c#

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I have been trying to convert this string to a DateTime object in C#

2019-09-23T08:34:00UTC+1

I've tried using DateTime.Parse but it is throwing an exception for

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert string to DateTime as UTC as simple as that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254211/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-as-utc-as-simple-as-that)

Comment: Can you share the code !

Comment: No this throws the exception for "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: It is unusual to see the UTC+1 part inside the string. Usually the ISO8601 format is used....where it comes from that string?
If you remove UTC from the string is should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry but you seem like a victim of [garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

That's an *unusual* format, that's why before I suggest a solution for you, first thing I want to say is "Fix your input first if you *can*".

Let's say you *can't* fix your input, then you need to consider a few things;

1. First of all, if your string has some parts like `UTC` and/or `GMT`, there is no custom date and time format specifier to parse them. That's why you need to escape them as a [string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals). [See this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241789/447156).
2. Second, your `+1` part looks like a [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value. [The `"z"` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zSpecifier) is what you need for parse it but be careful, this format specifier is *not* recommended for use with `DateTime` values since it *doesn't* reflect the value of an instance's [`Kind` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind).

As a solution for `DateTime`, you can parse it like I would suggest;

```
var s = "2019-09-23T08:34:00UTC+1";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'UTC'z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

which gives you `2019-09-23 07:34:00` as a `DateTime` and which has `Utc` as a `Kind` property.

As a solution for `DateTimeOffset` - since your string has a UTC Offset value you should consider to parse with this rather than `Datetime`
-, as Matt [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660536/how-to-convert-this-utc-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-c-sharp#comment103628437_58660981), you can use it's [`.DateTime` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) to get it's data like;

```
var s = "2019-09-23T08:34:00UTC+1";
DateTimeOffset dto;
if(DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'UTC'z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dto))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dto.DateTime);
}
```

which gives you the *same* result `DateTime` but `Unspecified` as a `.Kind` property.

But, again, I *strongly* suggest you to fix your input first.

Comment: Nice answer. : ) Would probably also recommend considering parsing as a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Ups, missed that completely. Thank you so much Matt. Added that part as well (:

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParseExact` to convert the string to datetime. Here is the sample code to covert the given format(s) to datetime

```cs
private static DateTime ParseDate(string providedDate) {
    DateTime validDate;
    string[] formats = {
        "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
    };
    var dateFormatIsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    providedDate, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out validDate);

    return dateFormatIsValid ? validDate: DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Then, use this function to convert the string. I am replacing UTC+1 to empty string

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string strdatetime = "2019-09-23T08:34:00UTC+1";
    DateTime dateTime = ParseDate(strdatetime.Replace("UTC+1", ""));

    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna this works with the exception of not accounting for the +1 in the time. How would I make sure that the time is accurate? Reason being is this is a tracking application and I'm parsing the ETA of deliveries so the UTA+1 is important

Comment: @SeanDavies you can use `ParseDate(strdatetime.Replace("UTC+1", "")).ToUniversalTime()` to convert the date to UTC time. Or you can simply add 1 hour `ParseDate(strdatetime.Replace("UTC+1", "")).AddHours(1)`